# Use case for sharing wifi over bluetooth?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, cellular-internet

What is the use case for applications like [PDAnet](http://www.junefabrics.com/android/) or [Android Wifi Tether](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/) supporting sharing wifi over Bluetooth? A friend and I were discussing this, and neither of us could figure out why you would need to redistribute wifi over a Bluetooth connection. In most cases, said receiving device would already have wifi. Any clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If her Android has a WPA connection to the WAP, and you don't have the password for the encryption, you could proxy your IP through her Android.

Answer (score 0):

Well, most mobile phones have Bluetooth, but many do not have WiFi. I believe one reason is that WiFi is significantly more power-hungry than bluetooth (logical, given its greater range). If you wanted to connect such a (smart)phone to the Internet, WiFi to Bluetooth would be quite useful.